# How to debug mex code using gcc (minGW) in windows

Tags: c, matlab, debugging, gcc, mex

I have written a mex code when I compiled I receive no error but it does not give me correct result. I would like to debug it, I am using windows platform and TDM gcc 5.1.0 and MinGW compiler because visual studio gives me error message about different standard since my actual code is in C not in C++. Anyway I would like to create a breakpoint and go through the code step by step, Can anyone tell me how to do that with my compiler in windows environment

Comment: You might have no compilation error but did you test the function in the C environment before exporting it to Matlab? One platform gave you an error message. Deal with a local implementation, first.

Comment: Yes I tested that in C and it works well not compilation error plus it gives me the expected output.

Comment: Honestly, I use mexPrintfs...

Comment: No I mean consider after running your code you encounter a problem that "Matlab has encountered a problem and needs to be closed " This is very hard since mxprintf wont do much. If you know any other technique I will be really appreciated